# Jquery currency validation according to current thread culture

Tags: c#, jquery

I am making control for currency where  I am giving the list of currency types in drop down and when user select the currency in drop down. The text box(of currency) validation should be according to that currency and if any type from the drop down is not selected then validation should be according to current culture.

[image]

My code for doing this server side is

```
 protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        // take currency Info using currency code which is given by user

        foreach (var culture in GetCultureInfosByCurrencySymbol(this.CurrencyISOCode))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(culture.Name);
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture.Name);
            currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
            cultureCurrencySymbol.Text = currentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol;

            RegionInfo currentRegion = new RegionInfo(currentCulture.ToString());
            cultureCurrencyCode.Text = currentRegion.ISOCurrencySymbol;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validating currency Entered by User
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <param name="args"></param>

    private void ValidateCurrencyFormat(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        if (currencyTextbox != null)
        {
            decimal num;

            bool isValid = decimal.TryParse(currencyTextbox.Text,
                                          NumberStyles.Currency,
                                          currentCulture,
                                          out num);

            args.IsValid = isValid;
        }
    }
```

CurrencyISOCode is property to which i am giving value from markup.

How can I do this validation in jQuery?

Comment: How are the controls implemented?  What is "the current culture"?  What is deficient in your current implementation, and what *is* your current implementation?

Comment: i have created control where i am taking CurrencyISO code from user and according to ISO code i am taking currenct culture and doing validation for that this all  things i am doing server side i want to do this validation using jquery how can i do that?

Comment: What is "the currenct culture"?  What *is* your current implementation (the actual code)?

Comment: I have added the code which i have implemented